# one or more multiply defined symbols found DESPITE #pragma once on header

Tags: c++, dictionary, header

I got a C++ project with the following files:

`Main.cpp` which includes `Game.h`

`Game.cpp` which includes `Game.h`

On `Game.h` I wrote `#pragma once` at the header start, and this header file contains an `std::map` with some predefined constants.

However, when I try to compile - I'm getting the common error

```
one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Pointing on my `std::map`

This is pretty much how `Game.h` looks:

```
#pragma once
struct a {
};

struct b {
};

std::map<std::string, std::string> weapons_db = {
    {"A", "B"}
};

class Game
{
public:
    ...

protected:
    ...
};
```

Comment: `#pragma once` only applies to the current translation unit. If you include the same definitions in more than one place, you still get multiple definitions.

Comment: how do I get around that?

Comment: Usually by not having variable definitions in a header. The preferred way is to not have any global variables at all. You can google for how to define global variables if you're desperate to learn from your own mistakes.